# Which ntp command replaces ntpdate -q?

Tags: linux, ntp

On older systems, where ntpdate is still available, I'm able to query an NTP-Server without setting

> ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org

and got e.g.:

```
server 213.239.239.164, stratum 2, offset -0.001191, delay 0.06012
server 185.220.101.76, stratum 3, offset 0.001658, delay 0.06416
server 185.220.101.31, stratum 3, offset -0.002385, delay 0.06377
server 159.69.144.253, stratum 2, offset -0.000134, delay 0.05711
```

So I see the NTP-Server is working fine and could be used.

On newer systems, where ntpd is running and ntpq is available, I tried.

> ntpq -p pool.ntp.org

but it responds `timed out, nothing received`
What am I doing wrong, what are the right parameters for ntpq command to see the NTP-Server is working and offer a good time-base useable for my systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found an answer to my own question:

> sntp -t 1 pool.ntp.org

is working without ntpdate and is available in ntp-packages. It is very fast and allows checking external NTP-server.
On drawback it always change the systemtime, so it is not only display the date/time.

Comment: will sntp -t work if you arent root, it should not change time if you are a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

some new systemd systems use timesyncd and have no client, but you can use `timedatectl
$ timedatectl 
               Local time: Mon 2020-02-03 18:56:37 CET
           Universal time: Mon 2020-02-03 17:56:37 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2020-02-03 17:56:37
                Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no`

Others have chronyc and you can use

```
chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^* schnitzel.team                2   8   377   107   +989us[+1030us] +/-   12ms
^+ dns02.wsrs.net                2   8   377   109   -877us[ -836us] +/-   29ms
^+ mon2.hostin.cc                2   7   377   108  +1541us[+1583us] +/-   44ms
^- 51-15-20-83.rev.poneytel>     2   8   377   110  -8564us[-8522us] +/-  176ms
```

Answer (score 0):

`ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org`

For me only tells how pool.ntp.org (a group in reality) is, ie what shape they are in and if they are reachable.

For the local host itself i would use `ntpq -p`, so for my own machine:

```
stefan@asus:~$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+gbg1.ntp.se     .PPS.            1 u  451 1024  377   10.221   -0.323   0.149
*gbg2.ntp.se     .PPS.            1 u  500 1024  377   10.250   -0.298   0.133
-sth2.ntp.se     .PPS.            1 u  352 1024  377   22.984    1.020  10.616
+mmo1.ntp.se     .PPS.            1 u  193 1024  377   15.313    0.225   0.135
```

This tells me that the machine (asus) just now prefers gbg2.ntp.se but gbg1 and mmo1 is alternatives.

sth2.ntp.se is unpreferred due to the jitter. Yes, my machine is stratum 2 itself (gbg1, gbg2 and mmo1 is stratum 1.)

`ntpq -p` tells who is the peers for the named computer, ie in your case the pool computers which maybe won't tell you that. `ntpq -p` alone will tell who is the peer(s) for the local computer, much more interesting.

And, no I would NOT think that timesyncd is good enough for a server !! You are hosed if the one machine which sync is done to is hosed !

Comment: For "ntpq -p" I need a working ntpd configuration, but that's what I want to check. So the old-fashioned ntpdate command was working independent from ntpd and if ntpdate succeeded I could use the same tested server for ntpd config.